# Export environment docker variable to file

Tags: linux, docker, environment-variables, dockerfile

I have very a simple docker file:

```
FROM tomcat:7.0
RUN echo $HOST_IP > /opt/serverIP
```

When I run my image (my-server) with follow command the file `/opt/serverIP` exists and it is empty:

```
docker run -e HOST_IP='172.16.1.1' -t my-server cat /opt/serverIP
```

How to write my environment value into a temporary file?

---

My docker version: Docker version 1.12.1, build 23cf638
This is my machine info:

```
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-36-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 7.703 GiB
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're confusing build-time variables with run-time variables.  The "RUN" command is essentially executed at build time.  Your "HOST_IP" value is supplied at run time.

The "CMD" instruction, however, is executed at run time.  To approximately do what you're trying to do, define a "CMD" that writes $HOST_IP to the file.  use "docker run" to run the image, and then use "docker exec" to verify the contents of the file.

Comment: Thanks, i change my docker file and my image is running. But the file not exists!

Comment: You'd have to update your post with exactly what you have now. It might also help to see the "docker build" output.

Comment: I risolve it using an sh script. Thanks and King regards